# "has no method 'forEach' TypeError" on Node.js-Ejs-Mongojs stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, foreach

I have this code on app.js that's a callback where all the content of the "locale" collection is found:

```
tester = function(callback) {
db.locale.find({}, function(err, locale) {
    callback( null, locale )
  });
};
```

This sets the "title" variable when "index" (the homepage) is accessed and pass the "locale" collection content to the variable "content" "stringifying" it beforehand (if I don't, I get [object],[Object]):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
tester(function(err, locale) {
res.render('index', {title: "This is a test server", content: JSON.stringify(locale)});
});
});
```

And this **forEach** in the view "index.ejs" which should only return the "title" collections field as a result:

```
<ul>
<% content.forEach( function( item ){ %>
<li><%= item.title %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

Anyway the problem is that I get a "'TypeError' has no method 'forEach'" when I browse the page.. What could cause this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly, you shouldn't want to `JSON.stringify(locale)`. Were you getting `[object][object]` from doing a simple `<%= content =>` and so then chose to stringify it? This would be expected as it would call toString() for the simple `content` token, but I would expect it to be available to the template as an array. Certainly would be in Jade Express templates. And what you have above is virtually the example [EJS shows on its homepage](http://embeddedjs.com/).

Comment: Turns out that you and Scott Gress were right! Stringifiying is not necessary when doing a `forEach` as it returns a string, not an array.. It returns "[object][Object]" when you just do `<%= content %>` without manipulating it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stringifying the `locale` object before rendering it.  Strings have no `forEach` method, only arrays!  So long as you don't actually plan on printing the whole `content` object to the page, and assuming that `locale` is a Javascript object, you can skip the stringify part entirely, and just do:

```
res.render('index', {title: "This is a test server", content: locale});
```